# Error running beautifulsoup (module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base')

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, html5lib

I am new to programming and Python. I am trying to install BeutifulSoup on Python3 to learn web scraping (using Jupyter Notebooks as an IDE) for MOOC. When I run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` I receive the following error

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         3 import ssl
>         4 print("done2")
>   ----> 5 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>         6 print("done3")
>
> ~\Desktop\py4e\code3\code3\bs4__init__.py in 
>        28 import warnings
>        29 
>   ---> 30 from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
>        31 from .dammit import UnicodeDammit
>        32 from .element import (
>
> ~\Desktop\py4e\code3\code3\bs4\builder__init__.py in '
>       312 register_treebuilders_from(_htmlparser)
>       313 try:
>   --> 314     from . import _html5lib
>       315     register_treebuilders_from(_html5lib)
>       316 except ImportError:
>
> ~\Desktop\py4e\code3\code3\bs4\builder_html5lib.py in 
>        68 
>        69 
>   ---> 70 class TreeBuilderForHtml5lib(html5lib.treebuilders._base.TreeBuilder):
>        71 
>        72     def **init**(self, soup, namespaceHTMLElements):
>
> AttributeError: module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute
>   '_base'

I have tried the following solutions:

1)    `pip install html5lib==0.9999999`
2)    `pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8`
3)     `pip install --upgrade bleach==1.4.2`
3) Updating BeutifulSoup (pip install)
4) Reinstalling html5lib to latest version after downgrades didnt work

Your assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how did you install `beautifulsoup4`?

Comment: I initially used 'pip install beautifulsoup4'. I have also made a copy and placed it in the file I am working in. Most recently I used pip install --upgrade bs4 (requirement is up to date)

Comment: maybe try this one: https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/issues/316#issuecomment-331662556

Comment: i'm glad :) cheers